# jboss 5.1.0GA web-console max memory

Tags: java, jboss

I'm running jboss 5.1.0GA on windows. I configured JAVA_OPTS like this:

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then


JAVA_OPTS="-Xrs -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
fi
```

Now when I open localhost:8080/web-console I see that my max memory and total memory are always limited at 1GB, and the free memory is more or less 100 - 200 MB
Why max and total are not similar to 2GB ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I was modifying the file run.conf instead of run.conf.bat